# 2 Sidebar Columns Layout (How)?

Tags: html, css

I wish to know how would you apply a 2 column sidebar via HTML/CSS
a fixed sidebar to the left and the other to the right?

Refer to this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/PXVSL/)**</kbd>

```
<header>

</header>

<div class="wrapper">


</div>

<div class="sidebar-l">

</div>

<div class="sidebar-r">

</div>

<footer>

</footer>


header {
  background:#00ff18;
  width: 60%;
  height: 120px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.wrapper {
  background: #ffffff;
  width: 60%;
  min-height: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
footer {
  background: #151316;
  width: 60%;
  height: 120px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.sidebar-l,
.sidebar-r {
  background: #00ffae;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 20%;
  height: 1000px;
}
.sidebar-l {
  left: 0;
}
.sidebar-r {
  right: 0;
}
```

If you want to use dynamic height for sidebars and keep it on window resize then add this script just before the `</body>` tag.

```
<script>
  $(function(){

    $('.sidebar-l, .sidebar-r').css({ height: $(window).innerHeight() + 'px' });

    $(window).on('resize', function(){
      $('.sidebar-l, .sidebar-r').css({ height: $(window).innerHeight() + 'px' });
    });

  });
</script>
```

And of course (if you decide to use the script above) don't forget to include jQuery library in your `<head>` section

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is the difference between <div id=""> and <div class="">

Comment: ID's must be unique, div with ID you can use in one instance on the page and div with class you can use multiple times on the page, same goes for every other HTML element. But in short if you have one wrapper div then you could use `<div id="wrapper"></div>`.

Answer (score 0):

Easy!

You really need to split the page's content into three columns; left, center and right. Then you can create three divs and float them all to left.

Eg:

```
<div style="float:left;background:yellow;width:20%;position:relative">Left column</div>
<div style="float:left;background:green;width:60%;position:relative">
  <div style="width:100%;border-bottom:1px solid #cfcfcf;height:50px;float:left">
      Header
  </div>
    <div style="width:100%;clear:left">
      Main content
  </div>
```

Right column

See jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cca5P/